# Call to a member function when i try to detach data (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

i got error like
Error
Call to a member function kelas() on null, what should i change in my code

modal kategori

```
public function kelas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Kelas'::class);
}
```

modal kelas

```
public function kategori()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Kategori'::class);
}
```

controller

```
public function removeKategori(Request $request)
{
    $kelasId = $request->get('kelas_id');
    $kategoriId = $request->get('kategori_id');
    $kategori = Kategori::find($kategoriId);
    
    $kategori->kelas()->detach($kelasId);
    dd($kategori);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
public function kelas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Kelas','foreign_key','local_key');
}
```

Or

```
public function kelas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Kelas::class,'foreign_key','local_key');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quotes around the class references in your relationship methods.

```
public function kelas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Kelas::class);
}
```

Hopefully this gets your relationships working correctly. You could test them by launching a tinker session (php artisan tinker), loading a kategori, and interacting with the relationship for it.

```
$k = Kategori::first();
dump($k->kelas);
dump($k->kelas());
```

etc